# Using ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground does not save Facebook permissions Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, parse-platform, permissions

After Facebook Login with ParseFacebookUtils im trying to Log the user's permissions but its always empty, here's my code:

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "user_location", "user_friends", "email", "public_profile");
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else  {
                        updateUser(user.isNew());
                    } 
                }
            });
```

Later...

```
Log.d(Check.TAG, AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().toString()); //returns empty!!
```

i have also tried

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().containsAll(permissions)
```

and always its empty.

Im using Android Parse Library 1.9.1 and Facebook SKD 4.0.1

This is driving me nuts! please help!!

Comment: Have you figured it out? I'm having the same problem. Even with the latest version of Parse lib and Facebook SDK.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, is there a known solution?